# Split string in chunks preferable at spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a tool to import data from one database to another. One requirement is that I have to split a string from one source field into three (shorter) fields at the target. If possible the string should be split at a space character. If the string doesn't fit completely into the target fields, the rest can be omitted.

Usually I would solve this using an UDF but unfortunately neither UDF's nor Stored Procedures are allowed in my scenario.

My source database has the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Organisations
(
    OrganisationID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    OrganisationName nvarchar(180) NOT NULL
    /* More columns omitted for brevity */
)
```

This table contains company names, for example:

> ```
> OrganisationID | OrganisationName
> ---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
>              1 | Microsoft Corporation
>              2 | S&T System Integration & Technology Distribution Aktiengesellschaft
> ```

During the import the records of this table should be inserted into a stating table in the target database. The staging table looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.OrgStaging
(
    OrganisationID int NOT NULL,
    Name1 nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Name2 nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Name3 nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
    /* More columns omitted for brevity */
)
```

If I would simply use `SUBSTRING` to split the name I would end up in the staging table like this:

> ```
> OrganisationID | Name1                                             | Name2
> ---------------+---------------------------------------------------+-----------------
>              1 | Microsoft Corporation                             |
>              2 | S&T System Integration & Technology Distribution A|ktiengesellschaft
> ```

But I don't want to split in the middle of a word so I would like to have the result like this:

> ```
> OrganisationID | Name1                                             | Name2
> ---------------+---------------------------------------------------+------------------
>              1 | Microsoft Corporation                             |
>              2 | S&T System Integration & Technology Distribution  |Aktiengesellschaft
> ```

To achieve this I came up with the following rather complex query:

```sql
DECLARE
   @MaxLen int = 50;     -- Maximum length of a target column

WITH
   SpacePositions AS
      (
         SELECT
               O.OrganisationID,
               CHARINDEX(' ', O.OrganisationName, 0) AS Position
            FROM
               SourceDB.dbo.Organisations O
         UNION ALL SELECT
               O.OrganisationID,
               CHARINDEX(' ', O.OrganisationName, S.Position + 1) AS Position
            FROM
               SourceDB.dbo.Organisations O
               INNER JOIN SpacePositions S
                  ON CHARINDEX(' ', O.OrganisationName, S.Position + 1) > S.Position
                     AND S.OrganisationID = O.OrganisationID
      ),
   SplitPositions AS      
      (
         SELECT
               S.OrganisationID,
               S.Position - 1 AS Position
            FROM
               SpacePositions S
            WHERE
               S.Position != 0
            UNION SELECT
               O.OrganisationID,
               LEN(O.OrganisationName) AS Position
            FROM
               SourceDB.dbo.Organisations O
      ),
   FirstChunk AS
      (
         SELECT
               D.OrganisationID,
               1 AS ChunkStart,
               MAX(D.Position) AS ChunkEnd
            FROM
               (
                  SELECT
                        S.OrganisationID,
                        S.Position + 1 AS Position
                     FROM
                        SplitPositions S
                     WHERE
                        Position BETWEEN 1 AND @MaxLen
                  UNION SELECT
                        S.OrganisationID,
                        @MaxLen
                     FROM
                        SplitPositions S
                     WHERE
                        NOT EXISTS
                           (
                              SELECT
                                    *
                                 FROM
                                    SplitPositions SI
                                 WHERE
                                    SI.Position BETWEEN 1 AND @MaxLen
                                    AND SI.OrganisationID = S.OrganisationID
                           )
               ) D
            GROUP BY
               D.OrganisationID
      ),
   SecondChunk AS
      (
         SELECT
               C.OrganisationID,
               C.ChunkEnd + 1 AS ChunkStart,
               MAX(D.Position) AS ChunkEnd
            FROM
               FirstChunk C
               INNER JOIN
                  (
                     SELECT
                           S.OrganisationID,
                           S.Position + 1 AS Position
                        FROM
                           SplitPositions S
                           INNER JOIN FirstChunk C
                              ON C.OrganisationID = S.OrganisationID
                        WHERE
                           S.Position BETWEEN C.ChunkEnd + 1 AND C.ChunkEnd + @MaxLen
                     UNION SELECT
                           S.OrganisationID,
                           C.ChunkEnd + @MaxLen AS Position
                           FROM
                              SplitPositions S
                              INNER JOIN FirstChunk C
                                 ON C.OrganisationID = S.OrganisationID
                           WHERE
                              NOT EXISTS
                                 (
                                    SELECT
                                          *
                                       FROM
                                          SplitPositions SI
                                       WHERE
                                          SI.Position BETWEEN C.ChunkEnd + 1 AND C.ChunkEnd + @MaxLen
                                          AND OrganisationID = C.OrganisationID
                                 )
                  ) D
                  ON D.OrganisationID = C.OrganisationID
            GROUP BY
               C.OrganisationID,
               C.ChunkEnd
      ),
   ThirdChunk AS
      (
         SELECT
               C.OrganisationID,
               C.ChunkEnd + 1 AS ChunkStart,
               MAX(D.Position) AS ChunkEnd
            FROM
               SecondChunk C
               INNER JOIN
                  (
                     SELECT
                           S.OrganisationID,
                           S.Position + 1 AS Position
                        FROM
                           SplitPositions S
                           INNER JOIN SecondChunk C
                              ON C.OrganisationID = S.OrganisationID
                        WHERE
                           S.Position BETWEEN C.ChunkEnd + 1 AND C.ChunkEnd + @MaxLen
                     UNION SELECT
                           S.OrganisationID,
                           C.ChunkEnd + @MaxLen AS Position
                           FROM
                              SplitPositions S
                              INNER JOIN SecondChunk C
                                 ON C.OrganisationID = S.OrganisationID
                           WHERE
                              NOT EXISTS
                                 (
                                    SELECT
                                          *
                                       FROM
                                          SplitPositions SI
                                       WHERE
                                          SI.Position BETWEEN C.ChunkEnd + 1 AND C.ChunkEnd + @MaxLen
                                          AND OrganisationID = C.OrganisationID
                                 )
                  ) D
                  ON D.OrganisationID = C.OrganisationID
            GROUP BY
               C.OrganisationID,
               C.ChunkEnd
      )
INSERT INTO dbo.OrgStaging
   (
      OrganisationID,
      Name1,
      Name2,
      Name3
   )
SELECT
      O.OrganisationID,
      LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(O.OrganisationName, C1.ChunkStart, C1.ChunkEnd))),
      LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(O.OrganisationName, C2.ChunkStart, 1 + C2.ChunkEnd - C2.ChunkStart))),
      LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(O.OrganisationName, C3.ChunkStart, 1 + C3.ChunkEnd - C3.ChunkStart)))
   FROM
      SourceDB.dbo.Organisations O
      INNER JOIN FirstChunk C1
         ON C1.OrganisationID = O.OrganisationID
      INNER JOIN SecondChunk C2
         ON C2.OrganisationID = O.OrganisationID
      INNER JOIN ThirdChunk C3
         ON C3.OrganisationID = O.OrganisationID
   ORDER BY
      O.OrganisationID;
```

It works as desired but I'm wondering if this can be stated a little more compact. I tried to combine the CTE's `FirstChunk`, `SecondChunk` and `ThirdChunk` into one recursive CTE but that is not working because of the `GROUP BY` clause which is not allowed in recursive CTEs.

Can this be restated more compact or is it already the best I can get?

Comment: Why do you have `Name1`, `Name2`, `Name3`? Is there also, or will there ever be Name4, Name5, etc...? Are you sure that's how you want to structure it? Perhaps a one-to-many relationship is something to consider?

Comment: What is the reason you split it up in the first place? Why not keep it as one column?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg the fields in the stating table just reflect the fields given in the target database. Both databases belong to already existing and more or less widespread applicatons and therefore cannot be changed. The idea behind my import is that data which is entered in one application (the source database) doesn't need to be reentered in the second application (the target database).

Comment: Still looking at writing a full answer for this, but I notice a // comment in the query, T-SQL uses -- for comments.

Comment: Okay, so I think the best way to do this would be to split the string at EVERY space. Then you can rebuild it from the individual words, stopping if you reach 50 characters. I'll try and get a proper answer up soon, just about to leave work so I don't really have the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A nitpick

This first point will not really change the query, and it is probably
only added for testing purposes, but an `ORDER BY` with an `INSERT INTO` statement does not really do anything useful (unless you insert
into a table with an `IDENTITY` column).

## Us a more compact style

It looks like you either have a very strong policy on style and
layout, or used an auto-formatter, because in some places, `SELECT *`
is written in two lines.  That is good, because the query is at least
well formatted and readable.  If you want it to be more compact,
though, you might want to skimp a bit on the newlines.

When formatting code more compactly, there is still "breathing space",
but the scroll-factor is tuned down a bit, so you have a bit higher
view of the code.  I find that it can help.

I like to use a combination of indentation to recognize the query
parts (my indentation is by no means the default in SQL) and a thing I
call "one concept per line", where each line tells me something that
can stand on its own for logic.

Not indenting `UNION` s helps to see the "equal level" of both sides of
the `UNION`, and prevents the lines from getting too long.

```
DECLARE @MaxLen int = 50;     -- Maximum length of a target column

  WITH SpacePositions AS
     ( SELECT O.OrganisationID
            , CHARINDEX(' ', O.OrganisationName, 0) AS Position
         FROM dbo.Organisations O
        UNION ALL
       SELECT O.OrganisationID
            , CHARINDEX(' ', O.OrganisationName, S.Position + 1) AS Position
         FROM dbo.Organisations O
        INNER JOIN SpacePositions S
                ON CHARINDEX(' ', O.OrganisationName, S.Position + 1) > S.Position
               AND S.OrganisationID = O.OrganisationID
     )
     , SplitPositions AS
     ( SELECT S.OrganisationID
            , S.Position - 1 AS Position
         FROM SpacePositions S
        WHERE S.Position != 0
        UNION
       SELECT O.OrganisationID
            , LEN(O.OrganisationName) AS Position
         FROM dbo.Organisations O
     )
     , FirstChunk AS
     ( SELECT D.OrganisationID
            , 1 AS ChunkStart
            , MAX(D.Position) AS ChunkEnd
         FROM ( SELECT S.OrganisationID
                     , S.Position + 1 AS Position
                  FROM SplitPositions S
                 WHERE Position BETWEEN 1 AND @MaxLen
                 UNION
                SELECT S.OrganisationID
                     , @MaxLen
                  FROM SplitPositions S
                 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                                      FROM SplitPositions SI
                                     WHERE SI.Position BETWEEN 1 AND @MaxLen
                                       AND SI.OrganisationID = S.OrganisationID
                                  )
              ) D
          GROUP BY D.OrganisationID
     )
     , SecondChunk AS
     ( SELECT C.OrganisationID
            , C.ChunkEnd + 1 AS ChunkStart
            , MAX(D.Position) AS ChunkEnd
         FROM FirstChunk C
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT S.OrganisationID
                          , S.Position + 1 AS Position
                       FROM SplitPositions S
                      INNER JOIN FirstChunk C ON C.OrganisationID = S.OrganisationID
                      WHERE S.Position BETWEEN C.ChunkEnd + 1 AND C.ChunkEnd + @MaxLen
                      UNION
                     SELECT S.OrganisationID
                          , C.ChunkEnd + @MaxLen AS Position
                       FROM SplitPositions S
                      INNER JOIN FirstChunk C ON C.OrganisationID = S.OrganisationID
                      WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                                           FROM SplitPositions SI
                                          WHERE SI.Position BETWEEN C.ChunkEnd + 1 AND C.ChunkEnd + @MaxLen
                                            AND OrganisationID = C.OrganisationID
                                       )
                   ) D ON D.OrganisationID = C.OrganisationID
        GROUP BY C.OrganisationID, C.ChunkEnd
     )
     , ThirdChunk AS
     ( SELECT C.OrganisationID
            , C.ChunkEnd + 1 AS ChunkStart
            , MAX(D.Position) AS ChunkEnd
         FROM SecondChunk C
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT S.OrganisationID
                          , S.Position + 1 AS Position
                       FROM SplitPositions S
                      INNER JOIN SecondChunk C ON C.OrganisationID = S.OrganisationID
                      WHERE S.Position BETWEEN C.ChunkEnd + 1 AND C.ChunkEnd + @MaxLen
                      UNION
                     SELECT S.OrganisationID
                          , C.ChunkEnd + @MaxLen AS Position
                       FROM SplitPositions S
                      INNER JOIN SecondChunk C ON C.OrganisationID = S.OrganisationID
                      WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                                           FROM SplitPositions SI
                                          WHERE SI.Position BETWEEN C.ChunkEnd + 1 AND C.ChunkEnd + @MaxLen
                                            AND OrganisationID = C.OrganisationID
                                       )
                   ) D ON D.OrganisationID = C.OrganisationID
        GROUP BY C.OrganisationID, C.ChunkEnd
     )
INSERT INTO dbo.OrgStaging
     ( OrganisationID
     , Name1
     , Name2
     , Name3 )
SELECT O.OrganisationID
     , LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(O.OrganisationName, C1.ChunkStart, C1.ChunkEnd)))
     , LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(O.OrganisationName, C2.ChunkStart, 1 + C2.ChunkEnd - C2.ChunkStart)))
     , LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(O.OrganisationName, C3.ChunkStart, 1 + C3.ChunkEnd - C3.ChunkStart)))
  FROM dbo.Organisations O
 INNER JOIN FirstChunk C1 ON C1.OrganisationID = O.OrganisationID
 INNER JOIN SecondChunk C2 ON C2.OrganisationID = O.OrganisationID
 INNER JOIN ThirdChunk C3 ON C3.OrganisationID = O.OrganisationID
 ORDER BY O.OrganisationID;
```

There is still some compactness to be gained if you write `JOIN` s with
just one `ON` clause on a single line, but only when that `JOIN` is
trivial (for instance on matching primary keys).  Especially in the
final part, I find the symmetry of the `JOIN` s to be clear.

## Use `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE` for edge cases

Four times you add a `UNION` on a subquery to account for an edge
case.  Three of those are when you want to split on `@MaxLen`,
because there is no shorter match.  But there is another way to do
that.

In SQL, missing data is represented as a `NULL` value.  When we use
an `INNER JOIN`, those `NULL` s disappear, because we can only join
on data that we know.  Adding missing data afterwards through a
`UNION` and a back reference (querying the same data but asking
where it is missing) is possible.  But we can also just take those
`NULL` s with an `OUTER JOIN` (mostly `LEFT` or `RIGHT`), and tell
SQL to replace missing values by something else, using [`COALESCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx).

### In the Chunk CTEs

In the FirstChunk, we only know that something is missing if we know
of all the organisations, so we need to select the data from the
origin as well:

```
, FirstChunk AS
( SELECT O.OrganisationID
       , 1 AS ChunkStart
       , COALESCE(MAX(D.Position), @MaxLen) AS ChunkEnd
    FROM dbo.Organisations O
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT S.OrganisationID
                     , S.Position + 1 AS Position
                  FROM SplitPositions S
                 WHERE Position BETWEEN 1 AND @MaxLen
              ) D ON D.OrganisationID = O.OrganisationID
     GROUP BY O.OrganisationID
)
```

Notice that we don't select `D.OrganisationID` for the first column
any more, because that can also be `NULL` if we can't split.  That
also means that we need to `GROUP BY` the newly selected value.

In the other two CTEs, we can just take the existing values of the
previous CTEs:

```
, SecondChunk AS
( SELECT C.OrganisationID
       , C.ChunkEnd + 1 AS ChunkStart
       , COALESCE(MAX(D.Position), C.ChunkEnd + @MaxLen) AS ChunkEnd
    FROM FirstChunk C
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT S.OrganisationID
                     , S.Position + 1 AS Position
                  FROM SplitPositions S
                 INNER JOIN FirstChunk C ON C.OrganisationID = S.OrganisationID
                 WHERE S.Position BETWEEN C.ChunkEnd + 1 AND C.ChunkEnd + @MaxLen
              ) D ON D.OrganisationID = C.OrganisationID
   GROUP BY C.OrganisationID, C.ChunkEnd
)
, ThirdChunk AS
( SELECT C.OrganisationID
       , C.ChunkEnd + 1 AS ChunkStart
       , COALESCE(MAX(D.Position), C.ChunkEnd + @MaxLen) AS ChunkEnd
    FROM SecondChunk C
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT S.OrganisationID
                     , S.Position + 1 AS Position
                  FROM SplitPositions S
                 INNER JOIN SecondChunk C ON C.OrganisationID = S.OrganisationID
                 WHERE S.Position BETWEEN C.ChunkEnd + 1 AND C.ChunkEnd + @MaxLen
              ) D ON D.OrganisationID = C.OrganisationID
   GROUP BY C.OrganisationID, C.ChunkEnd
)
```

Now the query is more compact, but also faster, because we add the
edge cases in the same "swoop".

### In the SpacePositions and SplitPositions CTEs

Yes, in the -Positions CTEs we do this as well, although this is a
bit less clear at first, and will probably not gain as much in
readability or performance.  For completeness, I will explain it
here as well.

The edge case is the final position.  It does not contain a space,
but needs to be taken into account as well.  Or does it?  Now that
we take `@MaxLen` where there is no space to split on, we will take
`@MaxLen` also when there is no space *left* to split on.  Which
may or may not be past the end of the input string.  Lets see what
happens if we just remove the `SplitPositions` CTE.  I will add
some additional test data to see what happens:

```
INSERT INTO Organisations ([OrganisationName])
SELECT SUBSTRING(OrganisationName, 1, 180)
  FROM ( SELECT 'Microsoft Corporation'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'S&T System Integration & Technology Distribution Aktiengesellschaft'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'VeryLongOrganisationNameThatWillHaveToBeSplitWithoutASpace Because It Really Is A Long Name, But In The Second Column We Can Split It'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'Another VeryLongOrganisationNameThatWillHaveToBeSplitWithoutASpaceButOnlyInTheSecondColumn, Because It Really Is A Long Name'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'AnotherVeryLongOrganisationNameThatWillHaveToBeSplitWithoutASpaceBecauseItReallyIsALongNameButNowItEvenExceedsTheLimitOfAllThreeColumnsWithAMaximumLenghtOf50Characters(WhichIsACombinedTotalOf150Characters)AndNowWeDon''tHaveAnythingToPutInTheLastBox'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'OneWordOnly'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'A' -- Single letter edge case
         UNION ALL SELECT '' -- Empty string edge case
       ) Data(OrganisationName);
```

Now when, after the query, we run

```
SELECT *, LEN(Name1), LEN(Name2), LEN(Name3) FROM dbo.OrgStaging;
```

The results are:

```
| OrganisationID |                                              Name1 |                                              Name2 |                                              Name3 |    |    |    |
|----------------|----------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------|----|----|----|
|              1 |                              Microsoft Corporation |                                                    |                                                    | 21 |  0 |  0 |
|              2 |   S&T System Integration & Technology Distribution |                                 Aktiengesellschaft |                                                    | 48 | 18 |  0 |
|              3 | VeryLongOrganisationNameThatWillHaveToBeSplitWitho |  utASpace Because It Really Is A Long Name, But In |                  The Second Column We Can Split It | 50 | 49 | 33 |
|              4 |                                            Another | VeryLongOrganisationNameThatWillHaveToBeSplitWitho |       utASpaceButOnlyInTheSecondColumn, Because It |  7 | 50 | 44 |
|              5 | AnotherVeryLongOrganisationNameThatWillHaveToBeSpl | itWithoutASpaceBecauseItReallyIsALongNameButNowItE | venExceedsTheLimitOfAllThreeColumnsWithAMaximumLen | 50 | 50 | 50 |
|              6 |                                        OneWordOnly |                                                    |                                                    | 11 |  0 |  0 |
|              7 |                                                  A |                                                    |                                                    |  1 |  0 |  0 |
|              8 |                                                    |                                                    |                                                    |  0 |  0 |  0 |
```

Now lets remove the SplitPositions CTE, and add the `- 1` to the
SpacePositions CTE.  Furthermore, we replace all references to
SplitPositions to refer to SpacePositions (of course).

```
WITH SpacePositions AS
   ( SELECT O.OrganisationID
          , CHARINDEX(' ', O.OrganisationName, 0) - 1 AS Position
       FROM dbo.Organisations O
      UNION ALL
     SELECT O.OrganisationID
          , CHARINDEX(' ', O.OrganisationName, S.Position + 2) - 1 AS Position
       FROM dbo.Organisations O
      INNER JOIN SpacePositions S
              ON CHARINDEX(' ', O.OrganisationName, S.Position + 2) - 1 > S.Position
             AND S.OrganisationID = O.OrganisationID
   )
   , FirstChunk AS
```

Which yields:

```
| OrganisationID |                                              Name1 |                                              Name2 |                                              Name3 |    |    |    |
|----------------|----------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------|----|----|----|
|              1 |                                          Microsoft |                                        Corporation |                                                    |  9 | 11 |  0 |
|              2 |   S&T System Integration & Technology Distribution |                                 Aktiengesellschaft |                                                    | 48 | 18 |  0 |
|              3 | VeryLongOrganisationNameThatWillHaveToBeSplitWitho |  utASpace Because It Really Is A Long Name, But In |                     The Second Column We Can Split | 50 | 49 | 30 |
|              4 |                                            Another | VeryLongOrganisationNameThatWillHaveToBeSplitWitho |       utASpaceButOnlyInTheSecondColumn, Because It |  7 | 50 | 44 |
|              5 | AnotherVeryLongOrganisationNameThatWillHaveToBeSpl | itWithoutASpaceBecauseItReallyIsALongNameButNowItE | venExceedsTheLimitOfAllThreeColumnsWithAMaximumLen | 50 | 50 | 50 |
|              6 |                                        OneWordOnly |                                                    |                                                    | 11 |  0 |  0 |
|              7 |                                                  A |                                                    |                                                    |  1 |  0 |  0 |
|              8 |                                                    |                                                    |                                                    |  0 |  0 |  0 |
```

Looks good to me :)